# Declination of adjectives after einigen

Tags: grammatical-case

I learned that after words like "einige, mehrere, etc." the following adjectives also have the same declination. However, I got corrected when I said "mit einigen meinen Freunde" to "einigen meiner Freunde". Why is it "einigen meiner" and not "einigen meinen"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it helps to look at the English-language equivalent:

> with some of my friends

As you may know, *mit* (English: *with*) inflects what follows it to the **dative** case (*einige* --> *einigen*). And *of* can be expressed in German with its counterpart *von*, for example:

> Von meinen Freunden [sind manche weg].

As with *mit*, *von* inflects the following noun phrase to the dative case. Concatenating *mit* and *von* like so

> Mit einigen von meinen Freunden [habe ich gesprochen].

is grammatical German but considered inferior style, especially in writing. (Some people may disagree and consider the double dative acceptable.)

Instead, you would drop the preposition and inflect the noun and its possessive pronoun to the **genitive** case, i.e., *meiner Freunde* (and not *meinen Freunden*, which is dative case). This rule supersedes the otherwise correct rule that you learned about matching the declination.

---

**UPDATE:**
I am reliably informed that I erred in the "bonus" part of this Answer.

In response to my own question, "But what if you stick in an **adjective**?"

> With some of my **good** friends

I had offered

> Mit einige**n** meine**r** gute**n** Freunde

That was correct. However, I erred in identifying "gute**n**" as dative plural. It is in fact genitive plural, the same genitive plural as "meine**r**" and "Freunde". My mistake shows how tricky identifying the case of individual words can be when different cases can be letter-for-letter identical and only functional analysis will differentiate them.

Answer (score 4):

What happens in your example is that *meine* turns *Freunde* from an indefinite group (some friends) to a definite group (all my friends). The same thing would happen if you used *diese, jene* etc. instead of *meine*. Applying *einige* (or *mehrere)* to a definite group makes no sense, therefore *meine Freunde* is put into the genetive case and the whole term *einige meiner Freunde* means (with maximum explicitness) *some members of the group which consists of all my friends* or just *some of my friends.*

The same happens in English, where you can say *some friends* or *some of my friends* but not *some my friends.* I could not find an example on the fly where German does not behave analogously to English concerning this.

Comment: Why is "some members of the group which ..." the literal translation of  "einige meiner Freunde". "Some of my friends" is. Why make it sound more complicated than it is

Comment: @Emanuel: You are right. However, I wanted to be this over-explicit to avoid any misunderstanding. But *literally* was definitly the wrong term to describe it.

Comment: I like this answer better. Since English and German are connected, I never stopped to look why there was an 'of' between 'some' and 'friends'.